# ¿Cómo sacar los valores de una tabla que convertí en grid?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo una tabla que tiene de propiedades como grid y utilizo el evento `doOnRowDblClicked` para que después de darle doble click me abra un pdf. Este pdf contiene datos que son de acuerdo a la fila que he elegido.

Acá está el problema: no sé cómo hacer para que después de darle doble click, es decir en la funcion `doOnRowDblClicked`, me obtenga los datos de esa fila de una de sus columnas para que a la hora de hacer el pdf sea según esos campos.

Les paso el código y cómo formé mi pdf. En este caso yo he puesto los parámetros, pero lo que quiero es que los parámetros pasen automáticamente.

```
<?php session_start();
include 'conexionguias.inc';
include '../../conectPitsPlan.inc';
$cnpplan=coneccion();

$id_personal=$_SESSION['itp_idpersonal'];
$filtrar   = $_POST['si'];
$fechadesde   = $_POST['desde'];
$fechahasta   = $_POST['hasta'];
$estado   = $_POST['para'];

$contador = 1;


/*to_char(des.fecretorno,'dd/mm/YYYY')*/

if(strcmp($filtrar ,"F.REGISTRO")== 0):

  $select = "select des.serieguia as serie, des.nroguia as nroguia, est.estadoguia as estado, des.codmensajero as codigo, trim(per.nombre) as mensajero, 
                  to_char(des.fecsalida ,'dd/mm/YYYY') as f_salida, des.total as total, des.entregados as entregados, des.motivos as motivos, des.reenvios as reenvios, 
                  des.anulados as anulados, des.perdidos as perdidos, 
                  (des.total - des.entregados - des.motivos - des.reenvios- des.anulados - des.perdidos) as ruta, 
                  tp.tipopago as tipo_pago, des.codzona as cod_zona, to_char(des.fecretorno,'dd/mm/YYYY') as fecretorno
           from despacho as des 
                  left join t_estado_guia est on  est.codestadoguia = des.codestadoguia
                  left join personal per on per.codigopersonal = des.codmensajero
                  left join personal pcla on pcla.codigopersonal = des.codclasificador
                  left join sedesprov sed on sed.codsede = des.codsede
                  left join t_ambitos amb on amb.codambito = sed.cod_ambito
                  left join t_tipo_pago tp on tp.codtipopago = des.codtipopago
                  left join personal perf on perf.codigopersonal = des.usuarioflete
                  left join personal perc on perc.codigopersonal = des.usuariodesp
                  left join personal perm on perm.codigopersonal = des.usuariomod 
                  left outer join zonas zon on zon.codzona = des.codzona
                  left outer join tab_zona_cantidad tzc on tzc.zona = zon.bonozona
                  left join personal perr on perr.codigopersonal = des.userasigna 
                  left outer join t_tablas tz on tz.codtabla='023' and trim(tz.codigo)=des.tipo_zona where des.fechadesp::date>='$fechadesde' and des.fechadesp::date<='$fechahasta'and est.estadoguia='$estado' and des.codmensajero='$id_personal' ";
endif;

if(strcmp($filtrar ,"F.SALIDA")== 0):

  $select = "select des.serieguia as serie, des.nroguia as nroguia, est.estadoguia as estado, des.codmensajero as codigo, trim(per.nombre) as mensajero, 
                  to_char(des.fecsalida ,'dd/mm/YYYY') as f_salida, des.total as total, des.entregados as entregados, des.motivos as motivos, des.reenvios as reenvios, 
                  des.anulados as anulados, des.perdidos as perdidos, 
                  (des.total - des.entregados - des.motivos - des.reenvios- des.anulados - des.perdidos) as ruta, 
                  tp.tipopago as tipo_pago, des.codzona as cod_zona, to_char(des.fecretorno,'dd/mm/YYYY') as fecretorno
           from despacho as des 
                  left join t_estado_guia est on  est.codestadoguia = des.codestadoguia
                  left join personal per on per.codigopersonal = des.codmensajero
                  left join personal pcla on pcla.codigopersonal = des.codclasificador
                  left join sedesprov sed on sed.codsede = des.codsede
                 left join t_ambitos amb on amb.codambito = sed.cod_ambito
                  left join t_tipo_pago tp on tp.codtipopago = des.codtipopago
                  left join personal perf on perf.codigopersonal = des.usuarioflete
                  left join personal perc on perc.codigopersonal = des.usuariodesp
                  left join personal perm on perm.codigopersonal = des.usuariomod 
                  left outer join zonas zon on zon.codzona = des.codzona
                  left outer join tab_zona_cantidad tzc on tzc.zona = zon.bonozona
                  left join personal perr on perr.codigopersonal = des.userasigna 
                  left outer join t_tablas tz on tz.codtabla='023' and trim(tz.codigo)=des.tipo_zona where des.fecsalida::date>='$fechadesde' and des.fecsalida::date<='$fechahasta'and est.estadoguia='$estado' and des.codmensajero='$id_personal'";
endif;

if(strcmp($filtrar ,"F.RETORNO")== 0):

  $select = "select des.serieguia as serie, des.nroguia as nroguia, est.estadoguia as estado, des.codmensajero as codigo, trim(per.nombre) as mensajero, 
                 to_char(des.fecsalida ,'dd/mm/YYYY') as f_salida, des.total as total, des.entregados as entregados, des.motivos as motivos, des.reenvios as reenvios, 
                  des.anulados as anulados, des.perdidos as perdidos, 
                  (des.total - des.entregados - des.motivos - des.reenvios- des.anulados - des.perdidos) as ruta, 
                  tp.tipopago as tipo_pago, des.codzona as cod_zona, to_char(des.fecretorno,'dd/mm/YYYY') as fecretorno
           from despacho as des 
                  left join t_estado_guia est on  est.codestadoguia = des.codestadoguia
                  left join personal per on per.codigopersonal = des.codmensajero
                  left join personal pcla on pcla.codigopersonal = des.codclasificador
                  left join sedesprov sed on sed.codsede = des.codsede
                  left join t_ambitos amb on amb.codambito = sed.cod_ambito
                  left join t_tipo_pago tp on tp.codtipopago = des.codtipopago
                  left join personal perf on perf.codigopersonal = des.usuarioflete
                  left join personal perc on perc.codigopersonal = des.usuariodesp
                  left join personal perm on perm.codigopersonal = des.usuariomod 
                  left outer join zonas zon on zon.codzona = des.codzona
                  left outer join tab_zona_cantidad tzc on tzc.zona = zon.bonozona
                  left join personal perr on perr.codigopersonal = des.userasigna 
                  left outer join t_tablas tz on tz.codtabla='023' and trim(tz.codigo)=des.tipo_zona where des.fecretorno::date>='$fechadesde' and des.fecretorno::date<='$fechahasta'and est.estadoguia='$estado' and des.codmensajero='$id_personal'";  
endif;

if(strcmp($filtrar ,"F.CERRADO")== 0):

  $select = "select des.serieguia as serie, des.nroguia as nroguia, est.estadoguia as estado, des.codmensajero as codigo, trim(per.nombre) as mensajero, 
                  to_char(des.fecsalida ,'dd/mm/YYYY') as f_salida, des.total as total, des.entregados as entregados, des.motivos as motivos, des.reenvios as reenvios, 
                  des.anulados as anulados, des.perdidos as perdidos, 
                  (des.total - des.entregados - des.motivos - des.reenvios- des.anulados - des.perdidos) as ruta, 
                  tp.tipopago as tipo_pago, des.codzona as cod_zona, to_char(des.fecretorno,'dd/mm/YYYY') as fecretorno
           from despacho as des 
                  left join t_estado_guia est on  est.codestadoguia = des.codestadoguia
                  left join personal per on per.codigopersonal = des.codmensajero
                  left join personal pcla on pcla.codigopersonal = des.codclasificador
                  left join sedesprov sed on sed.codsede = des.codsede
                  left join t_ambitos amb on amb.codambito = sed.cod_ambito
                  left join t_tipo_pago tp on tp.codtipopago = des.codtipopago
                  left join personal perf on perf.codigopersonal = des.usuarioflete
                  left join personal perc on perc.codigopersonal = des.usuariodesp
                  left join personal perm on perm.codigopersonal = des.usuariomod 
                  left outer join zonas zon on zon.codzona = des.codzona
                  left outer join tab_zona_cantidad tzc on tzc.zona = zon.bonozona
                  left join personal perr on perr.codigopersonal = des.userasigna 
                  left outer join t_tablas tz on tz.codtabla='023' and trim(tz.codigo)=des.tipo_zona where des.fechacierre::date>='$fechadesde' and des.fechacierre::date<='$fechahasta'and est.estadoguia='$estado' and des.codmensajero='$id_personal'";  
endif;


if(strcmp($filtrar ,"F.DESPACHO")== 0):

  $select = "select des.serieguia as serie, des.nroguia as nroguia, est.estadoguia as estado, des.codmensajero as codigo, trim(per.nombre) as mensajero, 
                 to_char(des.fecsalida ,'dd/mm/YYYY') as f_salida, des.total as total, des.entregados as entregados, des.motivos as motivos, des.reenvios as reenvios, 
                  des.anulados as anulados, des.perdidos as perdidos, 
                  (des.total - des.entregados - des.motivos - des.reenvios- des.anulados - des.perdidos) as ruta, 
                  tp.tipopago as tipo_pago, des.codzona as cod_zona, to_char(des.fecretorno,'dd/mm/YYYY') as fecretorno
           from despacho as des 
                  left join t_estado_guia est on  est.codestadoguia = des.codestadoguia
                  left join personal per on per.codigopersonal = des.codmensajero
                  left join personal pcla on pcla.codigopersonal = des.codclasificador
                  left join sedesprov sed on sed.codsede = des.codsede
                  left join t_ambitos amb on amb.codambito = sed.cod_ambito
                  left join t_tipo_pago tp on tp.codtipopago = des.codtipopago
                  left join personal perf on perf.codigopersonal = des.usuarioflete
                  left join personal perc on perc.codigopersonal = des.usuariodesp
                  left join personal perm on perm.codigopersonal = des.usuariomod 
                  left outer join zonas zon on zon.codzona = des.codzona
                  left outer join tab_zona_cantidad tzc on tzc.zona = zon.bonozona
                  left join personal perr on perr.codigopersonal = des.userasigna 
                  left outer join t_tablas tz on tz.codtabla='023' and trim(tz.codigo)=des.tipo_zona where des.fecdespachos::date>='$fechadesde' and des.fecdespacho::date<='$fechahasta'and est.estadoguia='$estado' and des.codmensajero='$id_personal'";  
endif;

$resultado = pg_exec($cnpplan, $select);

?>

<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main_pag.css" /> 

 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function doOnRowDblClicked(rowId){

        window.open("indexpdf.php");

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div >
<table gridWidth="900px" gridHeight="460px" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" id="tblToGrid" imgpath="../internacional/dhtmlgrid/imgs/">
  <tr  style=" background-color:#CCE2FE" >
    <td width="40">&nbsp;Nro</td>
    <td width="40">&nbsp;Serie</td>
    <td width="100">&nbsp;N.-guia</td>
    <td width="70">&nbsp;Estado</td>
     <td width="90">&nbsp;cod_mensajero</td> 
    <td width="100">&nbsp;Mensajero</td>
    <td width="100">&nbsp;F_Salida</td>
    <td width="80">&nbsp;Total</td>
    <td width="80">&nbsp;Entrega</td>
    <td width="80">&nbsp;Motivos</td>
    <td width="80">&nbsp;Reenvios</td>
    <td width="80">&nbsp;anulados</td>
    <td width="80">&nbsp;Perdidos</td>
    <td width="80">&nbsp;Ruta</td>
    <td width="100">&nbsp;Tipo_de_pago</td>
    <td width="100">&nbsp;cod_zona</td>
    <td width="100">&nbsp;F_retorno</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  $contador=0;
  while($fila = pg_fetch_object($resultado))
{
$contador++;
$bgcolor="#FF9999";


  ?>
     <tr >  
     <td  style=" background-color:#CCE2FE" type="ro"><?=$contador?></td>
     <td  type="ro"><?=$fila->serie?></td>
     <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->nroguia?></td>
     <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->estado?></td>
     <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->codigo?></td>
     <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->mensajero?></td>
     <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->f_salida?></td>
     <td type="ro" align="right"><?=$fila->total?></td>
     <td type="ro" align="right"><?=$fila->entregados?></td>
     <td type="ro" align="right"><?=$fila->motivos?></td>
     <td type="ro" align="right"><?=$fila->reenvios?></td>
     <td type="ro" align="right"><?=$fila->anulados?></td>
     <td type="ro" align="right"><?=$fila->perdidos?></td> 
     <td type="ro" align="right"><?=$fila->ruta?></td>
     <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->tipo_pago?></td>
     <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->cod_zona?></td>
     <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->fecretorno?></td>

  </tr>

  <?  
  }
  ?>
</table>
</div>

<div class="contorno_result" id="div_detalle" style="height:500px">
</body>
</html>
```

Creando el pdf

```
    <?php
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf=new FPDF();
class PDF extends FPDF 
{ 
  public $sucursal; 
  public $f_ini; 
  public $f_fin; 
  //Cabecera de página 
    function Header() 
    { 

       $this->Rect(1,1,213,31); 
       $this->Rect(1,31,213,1,'DF'); 
        //Logo 
       // $this->Image('../css/images/Logog.jpg',13,2,25,27); 
        //Arial bold 15 
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',14); 
        //Movernos a la derecha 
        $this->Cell(30); 
        //Título 
        $this->Cell(170,4,'GUIAS DE MENSAJERIA',0,0,'C'); 
        $this->Ln(2); 
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10); 
        $this->Cell(36); 
        $this->MultiCell(170,5,'REPORTE DE GUIA'); 
        //$this->SetFont('Arial','',6); 

        $this->SetFont('Arial','',7); 
        $this->Line(1,32,214,32); 

        $this->Text(12,36,'SERIE.'); 
        $this->Text(22,36,'ORDEN'); z
        $this->Text(35,36,'CLIENTE'); 
        $this->Text(95,36,'CANTIDAD');      
        $this->Text(120,36,'FECHA VENCIMIENTO');    
        $this->Line(1,38,214,38); 
        $this->Line(1,39,214,39); 
        //Salto de línea 
        $this->Ln(10); 
        $this->SetY(45);

          /*   $detserie = $row["det.serie"];             
          $detorden = $row["det.orden"]; 
          $cliente = $row["cliente"]; 
          $cantidad = $row["cantidad"]; 
          $fechavencimiento = $row["fechavencimiento"]; 
         */

    }


    //Pie de página 
    function Footer() 
    { 

      //Posición: a 1,5 cm del final 
        $this->SetY(-15); 
        //Arial italic 8 
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',7); 
        //Número de página 
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C'); 
      $fecha= date("Y-m-d"); 
       $hora=date("H:i:s"); 
      $this->Line(1,266,214,266); 
      $this->Line(1,273,214,273); 
      $fecha= date("Y-m-d"); 
       $hora=date("H:i:s"); 
       $this->Text(10,270.5,$fecha); 
        $this->Text(30,270.5,$hora); 
        $this->Text(148,270.5,$this->f_ini); 
        $this->Text(180,270.5,$this->f_fin); 
    } 

    function __construct() 
    {        
        //Llama al constructor de su clase Padre. 
        //Modificar aka segun la forma del papel del reporte 
        parent::__construct('P','mm','Letter'); 
    } 
} 

    //Creación del objeto de la clase heredada 
    $pdf=new PDF(); 
    $pdf->SetTopMargin(5.4); 
    $pdf->SetLeftMargin(4.5);     
    $pdf->AliasNbPages(); 
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','',7); 

$cadconex="dbname=basenex host=192.168.1.10 port=5432 user=postgres password=abc123"; 
$conexion = pg_connect($cadconex); 



        $cadbusca = "select
det.serie as serie,
det.orden as orden,
 max( cli.cliente) as cliente,
CAST(count(*) as integer) as cantidad,
max(ord.fechavencimiento) as fechavencimiento,
det.estadoveri as tpguia,
case when det.estadoveri='MA' then 'DOCUMENTOS MASIVO' when det.estadoveri='CO' then 'DOCUMENTOS COURIER' end destpguia
from despacho des
left outer join detdespacho det on des.serieguia=det.serieguia and des.nroguia = det.nroguia
left outer join personal per on per.codigopersonal=des.codmensajero
left outer join t_empresa emp on emp.codempresa=per.codempresa
left outer join ordenes ord on ord.serie=det.serie and ord.orden = det.orden
left outer join cliente cli on cli.codcliente=ord.codcliente
left outer join sedesprov sede on sede.codsede=des.codsede
where des.serieguia='001' and des.nroguia='761171'
group by det.serie,det.orden,det.estadoveri
order by det.estadoveri,det.serie,det.orden"; 

            $result=pg_query($cadbusca) or die('La consulta fallo: ' . pg_last_error()); 


    $pdf->AddPage();     

         while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
          $serie = $row["serie"];             
          $orden = $row["orden"]; 
          $cliente = $row["cliente"]; 
          $cantidad = $row["cantidad"]; 
          $fechavencimiento = $row["fechavencimiento"]; 


          $pdf->Text(13,$pdf->GetY(),$serie); 
          $pdf->Text(22,$pdf->GetY(),$orden); 
          $pdf->Text(35,$pdf->GetY(),$cliente); 
          $pdf->Text(100,$pdf->GetY(),$cantidad);   
          $pdf->Text(120,$pdf->GetY(),$fechavencimiento);  
          $pdf->cell(0,5.5,'',0,1); 

        } 

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Esto es una pregunta de JavaScript que ya se ha hecho antes. La voy a buscar para ponerte el enlace aquí.

Comment: gracias esperare tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Viendo el código por encima, se me ocurre que puedes hacer algo así como esto:

```
function doOnRowDblClicked(rowId){

    window.open("indexpdf.php?id=" + rowId);

}
```

Y luego, en el php, recuperar por el id los valores que necesites para montar el PDF.

Espero que te haya servidor.

Comment: es decir lo que has puesto me va permitir manejar esa fila.. d ahi tendria q sacar los valores segun su posicion? com qdaria masomenes¡?